# Ошибка при использовании BeautifulSoup4 на разных ОС

Tags: python, beautiful-soup, bs4

недавно начал изучать Python и столкнулся с проблемой - в Windows10 код работает, а на LinuxMint выходит ошибка

```
Unresolved attribute reference 'find_all' for class 'PageElement'
```

в этой функции:

```
def get_links(html):
    try:
        links = []
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
        divs = soup.find('div', id="rso").find_all('div', class_="dbsr")
        for div in divs:
            link = div.find('a').get('href')
            links.append(link)
        print('**links_list ok**')
        return links

    except TypeError:
        print('TypeError in get_links()')
```

И в Windows и в Linux ПО одинаковое (стоят Python 3.8 и PyCharm Community Edition)
Скрин ошибки на LinuxMint
[image: Скрин ошибки на LinuxMint]

В Windows10 ошибки нет
[image: В Windows10 ошибки нет]

Как можно обойти эту ошибку? Пробовал применить `.find_all('div', class_="dbsr")` отдельно уже к `divs`, но все равно выходит такая же ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm думает что soup.find() возвращает экземпляр класса PageElement, у которого нет такого метода. На самом деле soup.find() возвращает Tag, у которого такой метод есть. Запусти код, ошибки не должно быть.

Comment: После  запуска ошибки нет, но на выходе получаются 2 текстовых файла: в windows размером 1.5мб и с нужным текстом (затем из этого текста составляется WordCloud из 50 самых распространенных слов), а в Linux размер файла 39мб с лишним html кодом (в последствии WordCloud тоже получается неправильным). Основная проблема в этом, и я думал что все это из-за ошибки в той части кода.

Comment: Ну это уже вопрос немного не в тему топика. И для его понимания информации маловато.